# WIn-10 On Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

I have been running on 2008 R2 for a few years now though I had to replace the server hardware last year.  My server is simple (systems info. below) and is basically running MS SQL Server 2014, Pervasive SQL Server and Three (3) virtual machines via Hyper-V manager.  Each of those virtual machines have been running Win-10 Professional but now those VM's cannot update to the newer update of Win-10, I'm assuming due to UEFI support.

Nothing I have tried will allow me to update or install the current Win-10 version so I am considering moving up to Server 2012 R2 but am concerned that that will not allow me to VM the current version of Win-10.

Here is my two part question.

1. How can I update Win-10 to the newest version on 2008 R2 Hyper-V?
2. How messy could an in-place upgrade to 20012 R2 be?
3. Would 2012 R2 be able to support the latest version of Win-10 via Hyper-V?

Below are the system basics:

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- OS Version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
- System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
- System Model: PowerEdge T610
- System Type: x64-based PC
- Processor(s): 2 Processor(s) Installed.
- [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~1591 Mhz
- [02]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~1591 Mhz
- BIOS Version: Dell Inc. 6.4.0, 7/23/2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 Guests are officially supported on

- [Windows Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-windows-guest-operating-systems-for-hyper-v-on-windows) / [Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/supported-guest-os)
- [Windows Server 2012 R2 / Windows 8.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn792027(v=ws.11)).

It's not officially supported even on [Windows Server 2012 / Windows 8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/supported-guest-os), not to mention the older ones. As Windows 2008 R2 is already EOL for mainstream support (since January 2015) and extended support is ending on January 2020, and you already have need for Windows 10 guests, you would definitely want to upgrade.

In-place [upgrade of Hyper-V from 2008R2 to 2012R2 is possible](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19768.hyper-v-upgrade-hyper-v-server-2008-r2-to-hyper-v-server-2012-r2.aspx), but you should still be cautious:

> **Before You Upgrade**
>
> If you need to upgrade the server the recommended
> process is to:
>
> - ensure that you have a backup
> - move all the guest virtual machines to
>   known locations. Avoid having configuration files stored in
>   C:\ProgramData as that will get archived.
> - document all the virtual
>   machines, settings and VHD file locations if you have any static MAC
>   addresses set, make a note of these
> - make a note of all the iSCSI
>   targets you have configured and the SAN IP, drive letter or mount
>   point where these are referenced. recommend creating a text file in the
>   root of each disk saying what drive letter or mount point it should be
> - make a backup of the virtual switch configuration on the machine
> - backup everything again

You'd have much less downtime if you can perform a fresh Hyper-V Server installation on a different hardware, possibly even directly Windows Server 2016, and move the VMs between the servers. If this isn't possible due to financial limitations, then backups of the VMs are all in all.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, Microsoft's new servicing model and Windows 10 versions/builds has me a bit stumped but here's my take on it:

An update and an upgrade are not the same thing. Depending on what version/build of Windows 10 you're running you may already be at the latest "update level". To move to a later version/build is an upgrade, not an update. It sounds like you're expecting the upgrade to be delivered via Windows Updates. That's not the case. Updates to to the version/build you're running will be delivered via Windows Updates. Upgrades to the version/build will not.

These links may provide some insight:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-10-version-1709-fall/617a37da-8fc0-4f33-a3eb-59fe9082f925

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information